# VBA: run-time 1004 Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' error when screening for duplicates

Tags: vba, duplicates

In the following worksheet I would like to test row 3 for duplicates:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim c1 As Long, c2 As Long
    lCol = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If lCol < 8 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(3, 7), Cells(3, lCol))) Is Nothing Then
      For c1 = 7 To lCol
        For c2 = 8 To lCol
          If c1 <> c2 And Cells(3, c1) = Cells(3, c2) And Cells(3, c1) <> "" Then
            MsgBox "You cannot have duplicate values"
            If c1 > c2 Then
              With Cells(3, c1)
                .ClearContents
                .Select
              End With
            Else
              With Cells(3, c2)
                .ClearContents
                .Select
              End With
            End If
          End If
        Next
      Next
    End If
End Sub
```

When I test the code (by inserting a duplicate value or actually just any value) I get the following error message:

*Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' og object '_Worksheet' failed*

on line:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(3, 7), Cells(3, lCol))) Is Nothing
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You get into an endless loop here, because you are changing the values of the cells and the `Worksheet_Change` event gets triggered over and over again:

```
If c1 > c2 Then
  With Cells(3, c1)
    .ClearContents
    .Select
  End With
Else
  With Cells(3, c2)
    .ClearContents
    .Select
  End With
End If
```

To avoid it, disable the events like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False    
    'your code        
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```